# Promises that require output from other promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on some code for an express API that essentially reaches out to an external REST service for an authentication token, and then uses that token to do *stuff*. I'm very new to NodeJS, so I think I'm having a lot of trouble with the whole sync/async thing.

Right now my main problem seems to be that I'm getting `ReferenceError: err is not defined`, which seems to be related to the line in library.js, but I expect there are a lot of problems here, and will appreciate anything that can get me back on the right track.

index.js

```
library = require('library.js');

module.exports = async (req,res) => {
    // This is a test endpoint for prototyping code and testing calls.
    URI = "/some/uri";
    method = "GET";
    body = "";
    try {
        restResponse = await library.RESTCall(URI,method,body);
        res.send(data);
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(500).json({ errors: err});
    }
};
```

library.js

```
exports.RESTCall = async function(URI,method,body) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAuthToken().then((token) => {
            console.log("Token: " + token);
            try {
                // Do stuff with the token to make another call
                resolve(data);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

exports.getAuthToken = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            // Do stuff to get an authentication token
            resolve(authToken);
        } catch(e) {
            reject("Failed to get Facets Authentication token. Error: " + e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In index.js you have `json({ errors: err}` where err is undefined because you use `catch(e)`

Comment: `return res.status(500).json({ errors: err})` => `return res.status(500).json({ errors: e})`

Comment: [You are using the explicit promise constructor antipattern!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like just a typo:

```
    return res.status(500).json({ errors: e});
```

FYI this:

```
exports.RESTCall = async function(URI,method,body) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAuthToken().then((token) => {
            console.log("Token: " + token);
            try {
                // Do stuff with the token to make another call
                resolve(data);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Is mostly equivalent, but slightly worse as:

```js
exports.RESTCall = function(URI,method,body) {
   return getAuthToken().then((token) => {
     console.log("Token: " + token);
     // Do stuff with the token to make another call
     return data;
   }
}
```

But because you have async/await, can be simplified further:

```js
exports.RESTCall = async function(URI,method,body) {
   const token = await getAuthToken();
   console.log("Token: " + token);
   // Do stuff with the token to make another call
   return data;
}
```

Every time you see yourself type `new Promise`, consider it a red flag. I'd really suggest you take the time to learn how promises work.